# Eclipse diplomacy

Tags: eclipse

If you enter into a diplomatic agreement can you move your ships freely through each others territories without initiating combat? And can two allies move into combat against an opponent and have their ships team up against their adversary?

Comment: Eclipse players: Is this a duplicate? [Initiating combat in Eclipse](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12934/initiating-combat-in-eclipse?rq=1)

Comment: Note: a diplomatic agreement is *not* the same as an alliance. The expansion introduces rules for full alliances which, among other things, allows more than one player's ships to team up.

Comment: However with the Rise of the Ancients expansion you can form Alliances in which you can move through each other's territory and even fight together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To both questions, the answer is No.

From [the rulebook](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/732184/eclipse-rules-in-pdf-format), page 11:

> Your Diplomatic relations 
>   stay in effect until the end of the game, unless you attack 
>   one of the players you have Diplomatic relations with, or 
>   they attack you. **Moving your Ships to a hex where the other player has a disc or a Ship is also considered an attack.**
>   Both players then return the Ambassador Tiles and cubes 
>   to the owner. The cube goes back to a Population Track, 
>   chosen freely by the owner.